# wxPython error "takes no arguements (2 given)", when no arguments given

Tags: python, wxpython, event-binding

I've been trying to create a little python GUI for a database I'm writing. My main GUI works, but a dialog I've created for data entry throws the above error whenever the buttons are clicked (the rest of the GUI seems to work).

A cut down version of the code is below:

```
class AddDialog(wx.Dialog)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw)
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((300,300))
        self.SetTitle('Add')
    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        st = wx.StaticText(panel, label = 'Example')
        vbox.Add(st, flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, border = 5)
        closeButton = wx.Button(self, label = "Close")
        vbox.Add(closerButton)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose():
        self.Destroy()
```

The error message that I get is:

```
TypeError: OnClose() takes no arguments(2 given)
```

However, I don't think I'm giving it any arguments. Can anyone help this beginner in working out what python doesn't like?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
         closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
```

you are creating a link, where if the user clicks a button, the window will receive an EVT_BUTTON event, and your function OnClose will be called. It will call it with two arguments - self (which is true for any class function) and the event itself. You just need to change your function header to look like this:

```
def OnClose(self, event):
    self.Destroy()
```

and then it should work.

Comment: thank you, I didn't fully understand how the window handles events.